# When I go to the my domain name it goes to my app but just shows the IP address in the address bar

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

I have a react build that I am serving on an nginx server on a vps with contabo and a domain name hosted on godaddy.
I altered the A record in godaddy to point to my vps ip I switched the name servers from godaddys to my vps it loads the app like it should but the domain name is replaced with th ip address of the server. Please tell me how to fix this

the sites-enabled for nginx is

```
server {
      listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

  include snippets/self-signed.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  server_name blockface.fun;
  root /var/www/blockface.fun/html;
  index index.html;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/blockface.fun.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/blockface.fun.error.log;
  location / {
                #...
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
                #...  
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

When I run sudo ufw app list

```
Available applications:
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
```

Answer (score 1):

go to DNS Zone Management in contabo:
there will be 3 naming servers listed, make sure to add all against your godaddy domain(supposedly you already did that).
then make sure your domain's FQDN is blockface.fun(in the section below you should see it listed if you have added the domain-add it if you haven't), if thats what you want.
another recommendation(though not asked):
replace
example.com www.example.com;
with
blockface.fun [www.blockface.fun](http://www.blockface.fun)
in your sites-enabled file